Event listeners in imported TypeScript service worker not triggered
I’m trying to import a service worker file written in TypeScript using importScripts in another service worker file. After some checks, it seems that the file is loaded fine, but the event listeners defined in the imported file are never triggered or registered.
I am using NX to manage the monorepo, and I have set up the relevant configurations as shown below. Despite the file being imported successfully, the event listeners in the service worker do not work.
I suspect the issue but be in the way that webpack compiles the file and that the addEventListener are never called, but not really sure what's exactly the issue and how to fix.
Code Snippets
// project.json

"additionalEntryPoints": [
    { "entryName": "push-sw", "entryPath": "apps/web-app/src/push-sw.ts" }
],
"webpackConfig": "apps/web-app/webpack.config.js"

// webpack.config.js

config.plugins.push(
    new GenerateSW({
        importScriptsViaChunks: ['push-sw']
    })
);

and this is the compiled push-sw file that webpack emitted:
"use strict";
(self.webpackChunk = self.webpackChunk || []).push([
    [294],
    {
        5829: () => {
            const t = new URL("/", self.location.origin).href;
            self.addEventListener("push", function (n) {
                if (n && n.data) {
                    const i = n.data.json();
                    n.waitUntil(
                        self.registration.showNotification(i.title, {
                            icon: t + "public/logo512.png",
                            body: i.body,
                            badge: t + "public/badge128.png",
                            data: i,
                        })
                    );
                }
            });
            self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (n) => {
                const i = n.notification;
                n.waitUntil(
                    (async () => {
                        const n = await self.clients.matchAll({
                            type: "window",
                            includeUncontrolled: !0,
                        });
                        n.length ? await n[0].focus() : await self.clients.openWindow(t);
                        i.close();
                    })()
                );
            });
        },
    },
    (t) => {
        var n;
        (n = 5829), t((t.s = n));
    },
]);

Expected Behavior
The event listeners (push and notificationclick) in the push-sw.ts file should be registered and triggered when the respective events occur.
Actual Behavior
The file is imported successfully, but the event listeners defined in the imported file are never triggered or registered.
